# With gtk3, how do I make a write to the clipboard presistant?

Tags: gtk3

I stink at reading C code.gtk

In the sample [clipboard_simple.c](https://github.com/bstpierre/gtk-examples/blob/master/c/clipboard_simple.c)

it states

```
// NOTE: If you test this without a clipboard manager running, the
// new text saved to the clipboard will disappear as soon as this
// program exits.
```

[xclip](https://sourceforge.net/p/xclip/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/xclip.c) does not have this issue, and I can't figure out why.

How do I make a (text) write to the clipboard persistent?

### Many thanks,

New info:

I do believe the missing piece of the puzzle is:
[gtk-clipboard-store](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-store)

```
void
gtk_clipboard_store (GtkClipboard *clipboard);
```

Would someone point to the structure of GtkClipboard?   I think it is buried somewhere in /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkclipboard.h, but I can not figure it out.

Edit: if I am not mistaken, it is just a C pointer to a 64 bit integer